# Parallel computing course with concentration in statistical modeling

Tags: statistics, reference-request, soft-question, mathematical-modeling

Could you please recommend me a good online course that teaches about parallel computing that has a part about application of parallel computing in statistical modeling?
(currently I want to speed up the Monte Carlo simulation but would know more about the fundamental theory of parallel computing).

Thank you very much!